# Bitwise Operation in C/C++: ORing all XOR'd pairs in O(N)

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I need to XOR each [possible pair of elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) in an array, and then OR those results together.
Is it possible to do this in O(N)?

Example:-

If list contain three numbers `10,15 & 17`, Then there will be a total of 3 pairs:

```
d1=10^15=5;

d2=10^17=27;

d3=17^15=30;

k= d1 | d2 | d3 ;

K=31
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how O(n) relates to pairs of array elements?  Is the example an array of 3 elements?  If so, what would operations would be performed on an array of 4 elements?

Comment: can you be more clear about question?

Comment: This is a nice puzzle, poorly asked.

Answer (score 11):

Acutually, it's even easier than Tanmay suggests.

It turns out that most of the pairs are redundant: `(A^B)|(A^C)|(B^C) == (A^B)|(A^C)` and 
`(A^B)|(A^C)|(A^D)|(B^C)|(B^D)|(C^D) == (A^B)|(A^C)|(A^D)`, etc.  So you can just XOR each element with the first, and OR the results:

```
result = 0;
for (i=1; i<N;i++){
   result|=data[0]^data[i];
}
```

Comment: Nice.. Too bad my daily vote limit has reached :D . You'll have to wait for tomorrow. Anyways, TV (Someone please RVA) (Copied from code review)

Comment: TV = Theoretical Vote... Also since I have TV'ed you, someone might be kind enough to vote you for me and say RVA (Real Vote Applied) :D

Comment: @TanmayPatil Why should someone vote because a stranger asked them to, when they wouldn't have otherwise? Anyway, I have upvoted this.

Comment: Well, it's kind of a recommendation. If you don't want to, you obviously shouldn't. Thanks for your comment though, your notification brought me here back when my limit is not reached :D

Answer (score 2):

### OR everything, NAND everything, AND both results

Finding all combinations in O(1) is obviously impossible. So the solution had to be something ad-hoc reformulation of the problem. **This is a complete intuition.** (I don't have proof, but it works).

I am not sure how to solve it mathematically using boolean algebra since it involves finding all combination pairs, but I'll try to explain it using Venn diagram.

[image: Venn diagram for n = 3]

The required area is exactly identical to Venn diagram of OR except for the area of AND. Therefore they have to be subtracted. If you try it with `n > 3`, the picture would be even clearer.

[image: Venn diagram for n = 4]

The best way to test this method would be to simulate it with algorithms which don't have to be O(1). Anyways, you can try finding a direct proof. If you find it, please kindly share it with us too. :)

As far as your question goes, I'm sure you can implement it in O(1) yourself easily.

Good luck.

Comment: That's not the picture for N = 4; there should be 16 regions, but you only have 14...

Comment: Wolfram alpha confirms this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a+xor+b+%29+or+%28a+xor+c%29+or+%28a+xor+d%29+or+%28b+xor+c%29+or+%28b+xor+d%29+or+%28c+xor+d%29, and has the venn diagram. See the 'CNF' equivalence.

Comment: There are 16 regions, but two specific regions are null. The common region in opposite circles where remaining circles are absent. So there are 16 - 2 regions in this image. I tried my best to incorporate as many out of 16 sections as I could. Sorry that I couln't find a way to add those 2. If you can, feel free to edit it; help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise means that you only care about 1 or 0...

- The OR phase is true if at least one "pair XOR" is true.
- There exists only two series for which all "pair XOR" are false : `1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1` and `0,0,0,0,0,0`.

The solution is therefore a `for` loop to test if all items are  1 or 0.

And this is O(n) !

Bye,

Answer (score 1):

You can just do what is straightforward: loop over all the pairs, 'xor' them, and 'or' the sub results. Here is a function that expects a pointer to the start of the array, and the size of the array. I typed it here without trying it, but even if it is not correct, I hope you get the idea.

```
unsigned int compute(const unsigned int *p, size_t size)
{
    assert(size >= 2);

    size_t counter = size - 1;
    unsigned int value = 0;

    while (counter != 0) {
        value |= *p ^ *(p + 1);
        ++p;
        --counter;
    }
    return value;
}
```